# Moved react app with gatsby to S3, now I get errors in browser and usestate not working

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, gatsby

I used Gatsby to build and deploy my react app.  If I use `npm start` on my project, and open `http://localhost:8000` in my browser, everything works like it should.

If I use `gatsby build` and then copy my public folder over to my S3 bucket, the page does open, and the layout looks correct, but the state isn't changing for certain elements and I get console errors:

```
index.html:7 GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/webpack-runtime-405d85e0598b8c09729a.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
index.html:7 GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/page-data/index/page-data.json net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
icon-48x48.png:1 GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/icons/icon-48x48.png?v=edf3d310d67f8284a562bc3a58c3e761 403 (Forbidden)
manifest.webmanifest:1 GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/manifest.webmanifest 404 (Not Found)
manifest.webmanifest:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

My bucket is testapp1.app-site/index.html for reference.

Comment: You most likely need to make sure your bucket permissions are correct and that it is properly configured to serve files. It also looks like from your errors that your hostname variable (or wherever it's being defined) is not pointing to your particular bucket. I'd expect to see your bucket name somewhere in that url.

Comment: I made a clarification above.  The page actually does open and the layout looks correct, however the state isn't changing for the form elements.  I have a button that should appear when the drop downs have value, and they never do.  Also I have a section with an accordion based on state that won't work.

Comment: When you say "copy over" what exactly is the deploy process? The errors are saying that those files don't have the correct permissions.

Comment: I'm logging into my aws console, opening up my s3 bucket, and dragging the files from my PC to the browser form.  I deleted everything in the bucket, and re-copied everything in case a file had the wrong permission, but I'm marking the whole upload as public.

Comment: Before you copy next time, run `chmod -R 755 <build folder>` This will set the permissions for everyone to read and only the user to rwx (or run in your console on s3)

Comment: One issue I see is that in my error, is that the url is not correct, its missing my s3 bucket:  `<script src="/webpack-runtime-405d85e0598b8c09729a.js" async="">`

Comment: it there an env var for gatsby to set your hostname?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205628/discussion-between-archae0pteryx-and-baumli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

Make sure the permissions are correct. You can get the  permission info for a folder by running `ls -l` You will see on the left the permissions. here's a link to a [good explanation](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions)
You can then set the permissions for your env with the `chmod` command. Here's an example of how to set user, group, everyone permissions.

`chmod -R 755 <build folder>` [Check out this SO post explaining.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638796/what-is-meaning-of-755-permissions-in-samba-share)

Second:
Make sure any related hostname env var for Gatsby are set correctly. Here's a link to their [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) on the matter.

I'm not all that familiar with Gatsby TBH but hopefully one of those works for you.

[As per OP. Here is the link that ended up solving their issue!](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/)

Cheers.